# How to implement upload function using DTO?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-5, dto, aspnetboilerplate

I'm currently working on a project that uses ASP.NET Boilerplate framework and I'm starting to get the hang of using DTOs.

So I'm trying to implement an upload function where I can upload files/images, but using DTO instead of directly calling it from the controller. I would like some guidance on how to create it from DTO, including AppServices and the JavaScript, if anyone could help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/46294091/8601760

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [IFormFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformfile?view=aspnetcore-2.0) as a parameter of your service method.
Please find the sample code to use it. You can also create a Dto and declare an `IFormFile` property in Dto class and pass as a parameter to the method.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

public async void UploadFile(IFormFile csvInput)
{
    using (var stream = csvInput.OpenReadStream())
    {
        var currentLine = 0;
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
        ...
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Besides IFormFile, is there any other way for me to upload files/images?

Comment: Whats problem with `IFormFile`?

Comment: Honestly, I really don't know how to implement that. Like where do I place that? Is it in the app service or straight to controller?

Comment: in the appservice, you need to define the method like `UploadFile(IFormFile Input)`

Comment: I can't use IFormFile because I'm not using Asp.NET Core rather I'm using Asp.NET Boilerplate MVC. I tried importing like what you gave but it can't detect because I'm not using Asp.NET Core. Is there any other way for me to make this possible?

Comment: @Lynn use `HttpPostedFile` instead