# Is there a way to upload a file with the ABP framework

Tags: upload, aspnetboilerplate, abp

Does aspnetboilerplate provide the ability in the application layer to upload a file and have SWAGGER available to test the upload?

I can do this via MVC but can not get aspnetboilerplate (IApplicationService) to accept a file upload

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you do File Upload method in AppServices for aspnetboilerplate?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46294091/8601760)

Comment: @ivan-sager did it solved ?!

Comment: So I tried most of the options I found online including the sql table you mentioned and none of them worked...  But I am glad to say that I've managed to get a file posted using the interface from the ABP application layer and used IOperationFilter for my Swagger to work >>   The method is Task<FracPadDto> CreateFracPadPlan(CreateFracInput input, [FromForm]IFormFile file). So long story short it took a bit of work but I have a working version uploading excel with the regular ABP application layer --basically just taking advantage of abp dynamic API functionality

Comment: @IvanSager Post that as an answer or delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way post a file directly to ApplicationService, but the possible way to create an upload action in MVC which uploads the file in a directory and returns a uniqueidentifier, then the uniqueidentifier can be passed to the application service that can find the file in the directory.

Comment: See my above comment above. It seems to work and keep to the abp principles